# TraceWriter is inaccessible due to its protection level in HockeySDK.Xamarin v4.1.0?

Tags: c#, xamarin, nuget-package, hockeyapp

I installed latest HockeySDK.Xamarin v4.1.0 on VS2015 using NuGet packager.
But I got some error as shown.

```
HockeyApp.Android.TraceWriter.Initialize(crashListener);
...

CS0122  'TraceWriter' is inaccessible due to its protection level
```

How do I fix this error?

Comment: Mark the class public. Protection level comes from attempting to access something marked as private

Answer (score 0):

`TraceWriter` is not required anymore and thus not available anymore in HockeySDK-Xamarin 4.1.0. You should remove all references of TraceWriter.

Here is the [document](https://github.com/bitstadium/HockeySDK-Xamarin) about how to integrate HockeySDK.Xamarin.